# pacemaker master/slave configuration for postgres-xl datanodes

Tags: heartbeat, pacemaker, postgres-xl

I have created a cluster with 1 gtm (on t1), 1 coordinator (on t1) and 2 datanode (master/slave) (on t1 and t2 respectively) using postgres-xl.
I am trying to configure pacemaker heartbeat application using the below github link,

https://github.com/bitnine-oss/postgres-xl-ha

but I am getting the below status after configuration,

```
Cluster name: postgres-xl
Stack: corosync
Current DC: t1 (version 1.1.15-11.el7_3.4-e174ec8) - partition with quorum
Last updated: Wed Mar 14 11:41:20 2018      
Last change: Wed Mar 14 11:40:25 2018 by hacluster via crmd on t1

2 nodes and 6 resources configured

Online: [ t1 t2 ]

gtm:  started t1
coord:   started t1
dh1-ha [master/slave]:
   Started [t1]
   Stopped [t2]
dh2-ha [master/slave]:
   Started [t2]
   Stopped [t1]

failed-action:
dn1_monitor_16000 on t2 'master', exit_reason='none'
dn2_monitor_16000 on t1 'master', exit_reason='none'

Daemon Status:
  corosync: active/disabled
  pacemaker: active/disabled
  pcsd: active/enabled
```

Can anyone help ??

Comment: Where are you getting this from?   Have you looked at the logs?   Are you saying the server is failing to start?